# Передача ArrayList из Fragment в другой Fragment с Cicerone

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

как можно сделать один ArrayList, чтобы он был виден сразу во всех фрагментах ? Использую Moxy Cicerone

Comment: можно сделать класс с полем, который будете тащить где вам нужно

Comment: Изменять то его только в одном фрагменте смогу, а хотелось бы чтобы изменения были везде ))

Comment: пока не очень понял в чём проблема, вы его инициализируете где вам нужно, меняете где нужно и тащите где нужно, делайте что-то типа `var array:ArrayList<Objects> = ArrayList()` в классе

Comment: Попробую, спасибо